# Going beyond text messages in C telnet server

Tags: c, network-programming, telnet

For educational purpose, I'm supposed to write a TCP telnet server in C. Client is simply connecting to the server as `telnet` program. After connection is established, the client should see on its console a menu with some options, which it should be able to navigate via arrows and accept with enter. The choice is then sent to the server and some further interactions follow.

I have small experience with writing some UDP or TCP server-clients exchanging simple text messages but zero experience with telnet or any quasi-graphical front-end. The issue is I don't know how to approach this 'graphical' menu part in even general way. I spent some time browsing through the web, including RFCs 854 and 1408, but with little luck as most articles are either too low-depth or too specific. I reckon I simply do not know what I should be looking for - I only suspect it has something to do with NVT.

My question is: Is there any general-view but deep enough telnet manual/guide going beyond standard ascii `stdin/stdout`? Alternatively what phrases should I start looking for?

Comment: Telnet is really a text-only protocol. There no graphics ("quasi" or otherwise). There's support for receiving raw keypresses as they happen, but that's about it. If you can print your menu locally in a console (with e.g. `printf`) then you can use it with Telnet as well, just send it over the socket instead of using `printf` (or probably use e.g. `snprintf` to format the strings to send).

Comment: RFC should be really sufficient and comprehensive. If you want to continue this path you better learn to read such a documents.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude - Please consider posting your comment as an answer as this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to know more about [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

But [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) might not transmit them to your program (at least, most implementations of `telnet` won't always handle escape codes well). Then you are stuck (on the client side).

So you could consider using some other protocol. Did you thought of [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (usable thru browsers)? You'll find both HTTP server libraries (e.g. [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)) and client libraries (e.g. [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)) in C.

Comment: Which unfortunately isn't supported by all "telnet" clients.